# Vector Identity and the Scalar Product

Tags: trigonometry, fake-proofs

Ok, I have a question that probably has a very simple answer but for some reason I can't see it. Let $a$ and $r$ be two vectors of nonzero length with a common origin and let $\theta$ be the nonzero angle between them. Then, by definition of the cosine funtion,
$$
\cos \theta = \frac{|a|}{|r|}
$$
where $|\cdot|$ denotes the norm. On the other hand, the scalar product is given by

$$
\langle a, r \rangle = |a|\cdot |r| \cos \theta.
$$

Putting these facts together we have
$$
\langle a, r \rangle = |a|\cdot |r| \cdot \frac{|a|}{|r|} = |a|\cdot |a| = |a|^2 = \langle a, a \rangle
$$
which is a result that is independent of $r$ and thus makes no sense. What is my error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is that 
$$\cos(\theta)=\frac{|a|}{|r|}$$
is not correct except when $a$ and $r$ are a leg and the hypotenuse of a right triangle, respectively, which is not the case in general.

Comment: Indeed, that was a very silly error on my part. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition for cosine is wrong.  In $\mathbb{R}^2$, let $a = (0,1)$ and $r=(1,0)$ both radiating from the origin.  According to your definition, this would give you $cos(\theta) = 1$ even though the angle between these two vectors is $\pi/2$ and $\cos(\pi/2) = 0$.